# Draw a text in the correct "pieslice" in a circle using PIL

Tags: python, math, geometry, python-imaging-library, trigonometry

I was able to generate using Python [PIL](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) library the following wheel with colored segments:

[image]

However, due to my limited math skill, I wasn't able to create a logic/calculation to place the text in the correct `xy` location. I am trying to place a text in the center of the slice, near the edge of the circle (around `20` away from the edge).

My attempt (code snippet from a for loop that generates each slice):

```py
draw.pieslice(wheel_geometry, degree_1, degree_2, fill=color, outline="black", width=3)
draw.text(
    xy=(
        wheel_size/2 + (wheel_radius-20) * math.sin(math.radians(degree_1 + 5) + slice_degree/2),
        wheel_size/2 + (wheel_radius-20) * math.cos(math.radians(degree_1 + 5) + slice_degree/2)
    ),
    text=str(label),
    fill="white"
)
```

However, as seen in the picture, the labels are in the wrong position.

```
(1, 0xcc0011),  # red
(2, 0xeeaa00),  # yellow
(3, 0x10aded)  # light blue
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my attempt was actually correct, and the issue I had was accidentally swapping `sin` and `cos`. By using `math.cos()` to calculate the `x` position and `math.sin()` to calculate the `y` solved my issue and the numbers are printed at the correct spots.

[image]